# Actions Selenium Java mouse action drag and drop not working when cursor type changes after clickandhold

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, mouse

Actions Selenium Java mouse action drag and drop not working when cursor type changes after clickandhold

Use case:

1. Mouse cursor type: Pointer
2. Move to source element.
3. click and hold with mouse cursor type: changing to a rectangle block.
4. Move to target element and release.

Start Code snippet:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;


builder.moveToElement(fromWebElement).clickAndHold().moveToElement(toWebElement).perform();

Thread.sleep(2000);

builder.moveToElement(toWebElement).release().build().perform();
```

or:

```
builder.moveToElement(fromWebElement).dragAndDrop(fromWebElement,toWebElement).clickAndHold().build().perform();
```

end Code snippet:

The Above 2 code versions do not work fully.
The mouse pointer moves to the source element and clicks on draggable element as I notice the cursor type change to rectangle block to confirm click and hold.
But the action of moving to the target element with a draggable element does not happen.
If I manually move the mouse the cursor type changes back to the pointer and I see the pointer move to the target element without the draggable element.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Drag & Drop is currently not working.
For more information see the issue [w3c/webdriver#1488](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/1488).